# HTML redraw with ajax issue in PHP project

Tags: php, ajax, redraw, html-escape-characters, xajax

I'm working on a PHP assignment and having trouble getting an ajax call to properly redraw. Everything almost works except I have this one line of code that keeps giving me errors:

```
$line .= '<input type="button" onclick="$j(this).attr(\'disabled\',true).val(\'Updating...\');xajax_save_message(' . $error . ',' . '$j(\'#error_' . $error_code . '\').val());return false;" id="save_button_' . $error_code . '" value="Save" />';
```

I think I have an escape character in the wrong place. Currently, the error message that I'm getting is:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://127.0.0.1/dev/admin_eprescribing_error_messages.php
Line Number 1, Column 63:
```

The error occurs when I actually push the button to save. As I said, this is a PHP project which uses a library called Xajax to do ajax calls.

Any help would be great.

```
$j = "$"."j";
    $line .= '<td align="left">';
    $line.= <<<DELIMETER
    <input type="button" onclick="$j(this).attr('disabled',true).val('Updating...');xajax_save_message({$error_code},$j('#error_message{$error_code}').val());return false;" id="save_button_{$error_code}" value="Save" />;
    DELIMETER;
    $line .= '&nbsp';
```

Comment: is this error showing right after document load?

Comment: No the error is showing when I go to push the save button in the above line of code. I feel fairly certain that I'm have a misplaced ' or " or \

Comment: `xajax_save_message(' . $error . ',`, unless `$error` is numeric, you need to quote that string: `xajax_save_message(\'' . $error . '\',`

Comment: I added that and I almost got there but now have a 
Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported this never ends. Back to seeing what that issue is!

Comment: okay I have an extra ' before the jquery call and not sure how to get rid of it - I'm terrible with escaping characters: message(\'' . $error . '\', \'' . '$j(\'#error_message_' . $error_code . '\')

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$j = "$"."j";
$line.= <<<DELIMETER
<input type="button" onclick="$j(this).attr('disabled',true).val('Updating...');xajax_save_message({$error},$j('#error_{$error_code}).val());return false;" id="save_button_{$error_code}" value="Save" />;
DELIMETER;
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I'm almost there but I get this error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' => is there something that is left out? I'll be reviewing as well and thank you again

Comment: Thank you again - that got rid of all the errors but now the button disappears when pressed - that's not what I want but I think this is so close - I've updated my initial question to show you what I have -please note that the variable names slightly changed but that should not matter.

Comment: can you tell me which library you are using

Comment: That's a good question - this is an application that I just started to work on and I know it's PHP 7.4 and uses Xajax sorry I could not be more helpful.

Comment: I tested this on my side I think the issue must be in `xajax_save_message()`

Comment: Thank you for your help - I know it's almost there!

Comment: just verify the function.

Comment: I think I almost got it! Please see my code above - I forgot to add that this is in a td cell with another button would that matter with the DELIMETER? I've added more what the code looks like above

Comment: oh and I am using Smarty library as well